# Validating only HTML5 fieldset

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Is it possible to validate not the entire HTML form, but only a chosen fieldset inside it?

This is an exmaple of what I have:

```
<form id="SignupForm" action="">
    <fieldset id="1">
...
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="2">
...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to validate only fieldset 1 and not 2

Comment: Off course it is, it depends on your validation function, what are you using to validate? jQuery?

Comment: I'd like to use only HTML5 if possible, but if JQuery can execute HTML5 validation that would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the HTML5 validation, then use `text` type for the input field you don't want to be validated. Like this:

```
<form id="SignupForm" action="">
  <fieldset id="2">
    <input name="email" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="1">
    <input name="valid-email" type="email">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for effort. Hoping for a way of avoiding HTML5 validation on one of the fieldsets but my fault for not being clearer. Assuming both fieldsets contain HTML5 validation is there a way to only validate a specific fieldset